# Simple ListView using Firebase on Android. Issue with JSON

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to display a simple list of names in a list view. But I'm not able to figure out how. I think I'll not be able to use a modal class since all the values in JSON will have same property called **students**. My JSON data on firebase looks like this on firebse

```
{
"physicsClass":{
    "students":["John","Frank","Allen"]
},
"chemistryClass":{
    "students":["Gillen","Jason","David East"]
}
}
```

When I run the it crashes with the following error log:

```
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzaC(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseListAdapter.java:113)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getItem(FirebaseListAdapter.java:102)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:130)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1281)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Suggest any other way of implementing the above data in a list view / recycler view.

I'm using the firebase-ui sdk to display data in the listview. Below is the code

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference sezRef = ref.child("physics");
studentList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentList);
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,phyRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    textView.setText(model);
                }
            };studentList.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Comment: Please share some of your code about how you're parsing this json data

Comment: Obviously your "students" property is wrongly defined in your model

Comment: Probably, when you parse the json, you need one more step to parse students as the ArrayList, then take one from it if you need.

Comment: this is parsing issue, I suppose , try .toString() method with you rarrayList and if you are using Model then try to use GSON library or convert you json or arraylist into string and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

The error `Failed to convert value of type` means that when you retrieve you object from Firebase snapshot, you try to get the information as a `String` but the data in the snapshot is actually an `ArrayList`. That is why Firebase throws a `DatabaseException`.

Comment: Yes I understand but they should allow getting the data as a JSON format, which is a string. Throwing an exception is not nice

Comment: Well... If I remember right, `datasnapshot.toString()` basically returns the snapshot as a JSON. Maybe you can use it and build a `JSONObject` instead of retrieving with `getValue()`